# How we can change msdb values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a database called `Test` restore and create date is stored in `sys.databases` (system database). Is it possible to change its `create_date` value?

Comment: Messing with metadata is not a good idea.  However, I'm very curious as to why you would want to do such a thing?

Comment: You can change the create date by dropping the Test database and re-creating it.

Comment: As Dave implies, this is almost certainly an XY problem. What is your actual goal? Why would that value be useful?

Comment: No. This would be like changing your birth date because you don't like the date.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes, with sufficient time, ingenuity and ignoring the fact that you'll void your support, you *can* modify values in system tables. But the steps for doing so are (by design) quite complicated, they're very conspicuous (so not suitable for "covering your tracks") and it all firmly falls into the "you don't want to do this in production" category. Whatever problem you're trying to solve with this should probably be solved in another way.

Comment: thank for your answers, actually i was finding solution for my application licence. i am planning to incorporate licence with combination of metadata. if it cant change then its really helpful for my concept.